# Merge date if they are within adjacent hour

Tags: mysql

I have a list of date and duration :

```
-------------------------------------
Date                 |    Duration 
-------------------------------------
2018-08-08 16:00:00  |   00:45:00
2018-08-08 17:00:00  |   00:45:00
2018-08-08 18:00:00  |   00:45:00
2018-08-08 20:00:00  |   00:45:00
-------------------------------------
```

Desired table output :

```
-------------------------------------
Date                 |    Duration 
-------------------------------------
2018-08-08 16:00:00  |   02:45:00
2018-08-08 20:00:00  |   00:45:00
-------------------------------------
```

Could anyone tip me out on this mysql query ? my brain is lagging.

Edit1 :

I'll try a select to match adjacent queries for now :

```
SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE Date BETWEEN ADDTIME(Date, '00:30:00') AND ADDTIME(Date, '01:00:00');
```

Edit that field than loop to see if I fetch anymore lines.

Comment: This is a really easy problem to solve with a loop and a state variable, and a bit problematic to solve with a query in MySQL.  Do you have to do it in a query, or can you just select the data and process it in a external language?  Do you have the option of winding this into a stored function and doing it in the DB?

Comment: I have two options : store a selected result and do the job with php then update sql | or update everything with my sql. I'm curious about both options. I'm looking into the first one atm cause I have poor knowledge of mysql

Comment: This is an iterative problem which is not a good fit for the query format.  If you have the option to use PHP, I think it would be best.  Do it in a transaction (make sure you are using a transactional table type like innodb).

Comment: Ok I'll try to do the thing with php. Is the select I've mention in my post a good start to iterate from?

Comment: It's pretty easy in sql too, to be honest

Comment: mind enlight me, senpai ?

Comment: @Strawberry, please post an answer... I'd like to see and learn.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a1c2c/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
    (date DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, duration TIME NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO my_table
    (date, duration)
VALUES
    ('2018-08-08 16:00:00', '00:45:00'),
    ('2018-08-08 17:00:00', '00:45:00'),
    ('2018-08-08 18:00:00', '00:45:00'),
    ('2018-08-08 20:00:00', '00:45:00')
;

SELECT MIN(date) date
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))) n
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev >= date - INTERVAL 1 HOUR THEN @i := @i ELSE @i:= @i+1 END i
            , @prev := date prev
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev := null, @i:=0) vars
        ORDER
           BY date
     ) a
 GROUP 
    BY i;

+---------------------+----------+
| date                | n        |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2018-08-08 16:00:00 | 02:15:00 |
| 2018-08-08 20:00:00 | 00:45:00 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a1c2c/3